# AngularJS, Rails and ui-router not showing template after switch from ngRoute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I am trying to switch over from ngRoute to ui-Router but after I made the switch, the templates are not loading anymore.

I added ui-Router in my application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

This is the code in my app.js

```
var app = angular.module("alliance",['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, 

$urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
      url:'/',
      templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('pages/dashboard.html') %>",
      controller:   "DashboardController"
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("dashboard");
}]);
```

Original ngRoute code that was working.

```
var app = angular.module("alliance",['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
     .when('/', {
       templateUrl:  "<%= asset_path('pages/dashboard.html') %>",
       controller:   "DashboardController"
     })
```

It is now showing the default rails view.

I checked that the ui router script is loaded. Does order matter?

I have also played about with the state name, url but that didn't seem to be it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:

I changed the load order from application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-ui-bootstrap-tpls
//= require_tree .
```

and I changed the url in the config to /dashboard but it's still giving me the default rails view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matters, you need to load ui-router after angular and before your app.

Also the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("dashboard");` is wrong, your state is called `dashboard` but the url is `/`.
You need to define the url of dashboard as `/dashboard` and then `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");`

Comment: How do I control the loading order using rails?